# Discrete mathematics - pigeon hole principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

given sets A = {1,2,...12} ; B = {1,2,...15}

Let S ⊂ A x B , |S| = 21

Prove that there exist two different pairs (x1,y1) , (x2,y2)

in S such that

|x1 - x2 | + |y1 - y2| ≤ 4

- I think this solution can be proven by the pigeon hole principle, but I couldn't see it through..

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Pigeonholes don't look promising there. However, if you have an $S\subseteq\mathbb Z^2$ (of any size) such that any two points, then we can let the 12 points closest to each point of $S$ "belong" to that point:

```
    x
  x x x
x x s x x
  x x x
    x
```

and then if any point "belongs" to two different points of $S$ then those to points must satisfy $|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|\le 4$. (Convince yourself of this).

So the problem is to show that we can't place 21 such *non-overlapping* diamonds with their centers within $A\times B$.

Consider the rectangle $A\times B$ plus a boundary of width $1$ on each of its sides. The rectangle plus boundary contains $(12+2)(15+2)=238$ points.

Each of the 21 diamonds can have at most one point *outside* the width-1 boundary, except that we can place up to 4 diamonds in the corners of $A\times B$ with *two* points sticking out beyond the boundary. In total at most $25$ points can be outside the boundary.

The total area of the 21 diamonds is $21\times 13=273$.

But $273-25 > 238$.

---

In fact, by a closer accounting it turns out that no more than 10 points can stick out beyond the boundary, so even $|S|=20$ is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer from the university:
divide AxB into 20 sets as such:

{3k-2, 3k-1, 3} x {3m-2, 3m-1, 3}

where 1 ≤ k ≤ 4 and 1 ≤ m ≤ 5

this covers all numbers in the respective sets A, B and since |21| = S

by the pigeon hole principle we have at least 2 pairs in one of the sets and thus at least 2 pairs in S where |x1 - x2 | + |y1 - y2| ≤ 4